# select static id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

HTML:

```
<a id="status_like" data-id="123">like</a>
<div class="feedunderlikein" data-like-id="123">ali like this</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a[id='status_like']").on('click',function(){
    var idlike = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

When someone clicks on the `<a>` link, the content of the `<div>` below it should change.

I tried:

```
$("a[data-like-id=idlike]").html('sdsd');
```

but its not working...

*123* in `<a>` and `<div>` is coming from a database - both `data-like-id` and `data-id` are same in one `<a>` and `<div>` element and there are multiple of these `<a>`, `<div>` pairs on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a[data-like-id="+idlike+"]").html('sdsd');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple `#` (ID) elements (`status_like`)
 Use `.` (class)

```
$("a.status_like").on('click', function(){
     var idlike = $(this).data('id'); // GET THIS DATA (123)
     $("div[data-like-id="+ idlike +"]").html('sdsd');
});
```